# django filter querySet union?

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

there is situation in which when user search a keyword, the result will be 3 queries

```
a=model.objects.filter(icontains=keyword[0])
b= a.filter(icontains=keyword)
c= a.filter(istartswith=keyword)
```

And I want to return a result which combines a, b & c. But the condition is the order should be c,b,a and elements should not be repeated. I tried using union but the order is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

This works and looks a bit cleaner:

```
records = query1 | query2
```

If you don't want duplicates, then you will need to append `.distinct()`:

```
records = (query1 | query2).distinct()
```

Comment: I tried to do so, but the order was not proper.. that is the problem

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I completely understood the question but have to be tried:

```
from django.db.models import Q
queryset = Model.objects.filter(
    Q(icontains=keyword0) & Q(icontains=keyword1) & Q(icontains=keyword2)
)
```

Comment: thanks bro. but this wont work in this scenario

Answer (score 1):

```
You want to chain .distinct() [Django-doc] after a chain of .union(...) [Django-doc] calls:
from django.db.models import Q

qs = (
    c.union(b, all=True).union(a, all=True)
    .distinct()
    .order_by('-pk')
)
This will thus generate a query that performs a UNION ALL of c, b and a, and then perform a .distinct() to filter duplicate rows, and order these by primary key in descending order.
Note: It is important to use all=True here, since otherwise Django will perform UNIONs, and discard duplicates, and thus the .distinct() will have no effect.
In case the model has no pk, you can order by a different field, or use .order_by(...).
Note: You can construct the Q objects in a more elegant way with:
Q(field__icontains=keyword) | Q(field__istartswith=keyword)
so:
from django.db.models import Q

qs = Model.objects.filter(
    Q(field__icontains=keyword) | Q(field__istartswith=keyword)
).distinct()
This will thus generate a single query with a UNION of the matches of icontains and istartswith.

Note: Normally a UNION performs a sort-merge operation, and is less efficient than a single query with an OR. Django however optimizes this, and will generate a query with ORs, and a DISTINCT on top, so it is perfectly fine to use .union(...) here
```